# tkinter.Tk() error that kills and logoff my MacBook Pro

Tags: python, tkinter

When I run root=tkinter.Tk()
or just Tkinter.Tk() on my Mac it just kills everything and logs me off.

I have tried reinstalling the whole OS and then installed python threw brew but the problem still remains.

I'm using python3 but the same problem is there in python2

I'm currently running MacOS: 10.14.6

```
The error:

 >>> import tkinter
 >>> tkinter.Tk()
 <tkinter.Tk object .>

>>> 2019-08-07 08:49:48.988 python[917:21078] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-08-07 08:49:48.988 python[917:21078] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-08-07 08:49:48.988 python[917:21078] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-08-07 08:49:48.988 python[917:21078] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-08-07 08:49:48.988 python[917:21078] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-08-07 08:49:48.988 python[917:21078] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-08-07 08:49:48.988 python[917:21078] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-08-07 08:49:48.988 python[917:21078] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-08-07 08:49:48.988 python[917:21078] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-08-07 08:49:48.988 python[917:21078] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-08-07 08:49:48.988 python[917:21078] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-08-07 08:49:48.988 python[917:21078] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-08-07 08:49:48.988 python[917:21078] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-08-07 08:49:48.988 python[917:21078] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-08-07 08:49:48.989 python[917:21078] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
2019-08-07 08:49:48.989 python[917:21078] CGSTrackingRegionSetIsEnabled returned CG error 268435459
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in MacOS 10.14.6.

See https://bugs.python.org/issue37833

Answer (score 0):

Using a virtualenv to run code solved my problem.