# Tkinter crashes macOS 10.14.6

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I'm using macOS 10.14.6 with Python 3.8.2 and tk version 8.6.8, when I run any tk related code, even like this:

```
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('my window')
window.geometry('200x100')

window.mainloop()
```

The system will be crashed (screen blacked out and then logged off and reboot with login screen)

I searched online and most people say it is old version tk's bug, but I think I'm using a newer version of tk 8.6.8 and python 3.8.2. So I'm confused about that.

Comment: What's the model fo your MacBook(e.g. 2011 MacBook Air)?

Comment: Pick one from [` [tkinter] macos crash`(https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%5Btkinter%5D+macos+crash)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter crashes computer after MacOS 10.14.6 update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57435896/tkinter-crashes-computer-after-macos-10-14-6-update)

Comment: @SergioLey-Languren Hi, I'm using MacBook Pro 15-inch 2018. And I checked the link that you provided, they say this looks like a macOS bug and could be solved in macOS 10.15. But I didn't find how to solve it without update to 10.15

Answer (score 0):

You need add library `tkmacosx`.

Try this:

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkmacosx import Label


window = tk.Tk()
window.title('my window')
window.geometry('200x100')

label = Label(window, text=f'Tkinter crashes macOS 10.14.6')
label.pack()

window.mainloop()
```