# How to make Thonny use installed Python 3.9 (macos)?

Tags: thonny

I'm on macos 10.14.6, with Thonny 3.3.3 / Darwin 18.7.0 / Python 3.7.9 / Tk 8.6.8. I'm using Thonny to program a RaspPi Pico.

Thonny crashes a lot - apparently because of bugs in the tkinter tk library. (According to searches - [Tkinter crashes computer after MacOS 10.14.6 update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57435896/tkinter-crashes-computer-after-macos-10-14-6-update) )

I've installed the official Python 3.9.1  - but it seems that also has tk 8.6.

Can I get Thonny to use Python 3.9.1?  And will that help stop the crashes?

Or, can we get Thonny to use the older system installed Tk, which is 8.5? Will that help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try installing the universal variant of Python, which is built with newer Tk: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.1/python-3.9.1-macos11.0.pkg (it says macos11, but it should work in 10.9+ macOS-es as well).

After you have installed it, open Terminal and run `python3.9 -m pip install thonny` and then `python3.9 -m thonny`. The UI won't be 100% same as with separate application bundle (eg. the main menu will be called "Python" and not "Thonny"), but the main features should work the same.

Please let me know whether this works better for you!

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I've actually been running Thonny 3.3.1-alt since the release comments suggested a newer Tk in it (8.6.10).  Maybe that has the same effect as your suggestion?  It has been running OK this week. I really should load Thonny 3.3.3 again and verify that it crashes more often. Yes, I had to pull the Pico support files over from Thonny 3.3.3 but that wasn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you open a prompt and run the command below, it will update Thonny and python as well:

```
pip install thonny
```

source: https://pypi.org/project/thonny/